# Как зашифровать (обфускатор) код в c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, обфускация

Здравствуйте, пишу немного на c# WPF, идет полная привязка программы к серверу, т.е. основные действия без ответа сервера программа не выполнит. 
Как возможно сделать так, чтоб чтоб исходный код не было видно? Чем сделать обфускацию чтоб обычный пользователь за 2 клика не снял ее и соответственно, чтоб из-за этого не появились проблемы с антивирусом?
Все доступные обфускаторы которые я находил легко снимаются за 2 клика. Мне не нужна любая другая защита, просто не читаемый вообще код нужен, как это сделать?

Comment: Уточните: сервер, который вы упомянули, ваш? Если да, то сделайте всю основную бизнес-логику, все вычисления в нём. А wpf-клиент будет лишь отображать готовые данные. Таким образом, не будет смысла взламывать клиент.

Answer (score 3):

Аверы так и так будут срабатывать на большинство защит, т.к. коммерческие протекторы загаживают вирусописатели. Делают обычно несколько ступеней защиты, например:

1) Накрываем сам код обфуксатором (дотфуксатор и т.д., а лучше парочкой), который как раз переименовывает поля и методы, а так же в ряде случаев делает недоступным .exe для рефлектора (но опять же это правится вручную).

2) Накрываем уже накрытый код протектором (Enigma, WinLicense и т.д.)

p.s. самое важное - проверить софт после протектора и обфуксатора. Частенько что то ломается и приходится менять алгоритм защиты.

p.p.s. в связи с особенностью самой платформы .NET, а именно JIT компиляцией - на нем не существует абсолютной защиты от "вскрытия". С нативный кодом можно гораздо лучше защититься от вскрытия, но опять же - ломается все, и зависит это только от опыта реверсера.

Answer (score 2):

Любой .NET язык язык в итоге компилируется в IL. Декомпиляторы преобразуют IL обратно в C#, но при этом IL гораздо более функциональный нежели C#. По этому, для защиты вы можете прибегнуть к применению IL инструкций, которые не имеют аналогов на C#. В прочем многие декомпиляторы понимают такие финты. По этому рекомендую прибегнуть к более простому и дешевому способу - напишите критичные узлы на С++, напишите для них обертку с помощью Managed C++. Обертка позволит .NET среде работать с плюсами в управляемом контексте. Важно! Хоть плюсы и быстрые, не используйте такой метод в критично важных в плане производительности узлах, по тому, что маршалинг не бесплатный.